# choosing specific values on the X axis when using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph showing the number of events at the Olympics as a function of the year that a specific Olympic took place.

My data frame is called supertable and it consists of 2 columns, the first is the year and the second is the number of events in the games held that year.

My problem is that on the x axis I only get the years 1920 and 1980 and I would like to have 1920,1950,1980,2010

this is my code

```
ggplot(data = supertable,aes(x=year,y=no.of.events))+geom_point(colour='red')+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1920,1950,1980,2010))
```

This is the picture  I get

[image]

I tried doing this

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1920,1950,1980,2010),limits=c(1920,1950,1980,2010)
```

but it didn't help

I am assuming It is some thing small that I am missing, I tried searching for the answer but didn't find it.

Comment: Please post your data using `dput`

Comment: `limits` should be of length 2: a minimum and a maximum.

Comment: when i do that I get the folowing error 26                                               rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Comment: In R v 3.3.0 and ggplot2 v 2.1.0 this should work: `ggplot(data = supertable, aes(x=year,y=no.of.events)) + geom_point(colour='red') + scale_x_discrete(limits=c(1920,1950,1980,2010))` Please post your data if it doesn't.

Comment: its not working I will post data

Comment: You need `scale_x_continuous`

Answer (score 0):

Your x-axis is a continuous variable, so you need to use `scale_x_continuous`.

You used `breaks` correctly to indicate where your ticks on the x axis are, but the `limits` value should be a `c(min, max)` of the range of the plot you want to show.

Try this: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1920,1950,1980,2010), limits = c(1920, 2019))`